# native javascript for on('click keyup')

Tags: javascript

I am looking to bind onclick, onkeyup together and figure out a native JS version of below. Can anyone help please?

```
on("click keyup", ".searchButton",function(){
// code here
});
```

Comment: you want the same handler for all those events

Comment: @Ramanlfc something like that or better. I have the jquery code but I need to have native JS code also

Comment: Btw, if your element with class `searchButton` was real `<button>` or `<input>`, it will fire `click` event on ENTER or SPACE press. It is standard accessibility mapping and generally what user usually expects. Your extra `keyup` will fire on any key, what might not be intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

```
function addEvents(elm, events, handler){

    for(var i = 0 ;i< events.length; i++){

       elm.addEventListener( events[i] ,handler ,false); 

    }  
}
```

you'll have to put event names in an array like `var ev = ['click','keyup'];`

https://jsfiddle.net/f9dfjftk/

Comment: This does not deal with the fact that `.searchButton` refers to multiple elemenets.

Answer (score 1):

Native solution could be using global listener with className checking, like:

```js
function dosomething(ev){
  var tgt = ev.target;
  var log = document.getElementById('log');
  if( !tgt.classList.contains('something') ) {
    log.innerHTML += 'ignoring<br>';
    return true
  }
  log.innerHTML += tgt.tagName + ' ' + tgt.className + '<br>';
}
document.body.addEventListener('click',dosomething);
document.body.addEventListener('keyup',dosomething);
```

```html
<button type="button" class="something">something</button>
<button type="button">not something</button>
<input type="text" class="something" placeholder="something">
<input type="text" placeholder="not something">
<div id="log"></div>
```